# Screen tearing when using xrandr and x11vnc on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vnc, xrandr, tearing

I am trying to use my android phone as a second monitor for my Ubuntu.
I am following [this](https://blog.8bitbuddhism.com/2019/12/01/how-to-use-your-android-tablet-as-second-monitor/) blog.

This is the `20-virtual.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "intelgpu0"
Driver "intel"
Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
EndSection
```

and this is the script for the virtual desktop and VNC server

```
#!/bin/bash

W=798      # Virtual display width
H=393      # Virtual display height
O=VIRTUAL1  # The name of the virtual display (check using xrandr)
P=eDP1      # The name of your physical display (check using xrandr)
PW=$(xrandr --current | grep \* | awk '{print $1;}' | cut -d x -f 1)

# Create the virtual display
gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | xargs xrandr --newmode
gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' | xargs xrandr --addmode $O
gtf $W $H 60 | sed '3q;d' | sed 's/Modeline//g' | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' | xargs xrandr --output $O --right-of $P --mode
    
# Forward the VNC port to your device and start a VNC session
adb reverse tcp:5900 tcp:5900
x11vnc -localhost -clip ${W}x${H}+${PW}+0

# When the session ends, turn off the virtual display
xrandr --output $O --off
```

Image of the desktop after running the script

[image]

Also sometimes the system freezes and only the mouse works (then I have to either reboot the system or restart the gdm)

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-virtual.conf` change the driver to `"modesetting"`

This is how your `20-virtual.conf` file should look

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "modesetting"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: `xrandr` doesn't show VIRTUAL1 anymore and running the script gives ``xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"
warning: output VIRTUAL1 not found; ignoring``

Comment: run `xrandr`  and you'll see different disconnected outputs, in my case `DP-1-1 disconnected HDMI-1-1 disconnected DP-1-2 disconnected`. Now replace `VIRTUAL1` with `DP-1-1`. Also verify if `eDP1` changed to `eDP-1`. This happens when changing dirver from `intel` to `modesetting`

Comment: I don't have DP-* something, I only have eDP-1 and HDMI-1

Comment: then just try with `HDMI-1` instead of `VIRTUAL1`, it should work

Comment: No, it doesn't works with HDMI-1

Comment: Edit your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file(make a copy before editing) and change the section device to whats in this [link](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/bc7b9f424e3d5deb0c0b8bba990b1bc5#2-configure-xorg) copy the second configuration from the link.